# How can hostnames vary without having to add another name?

Tags: linux, networking, scripting, networkmanager

i want acces all subdomain name without add manualy

i tried with but doesn't work

```
127.0.0.6 *.azka.dev
```

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   noob-Modern-14-B5M

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

# custom domain

127.0.0.6 azka.dev
127.0.0.6 azka.azka.dev
127.0.0.6 api.azka.dev
127.0.0.6 heroku.azka.dev
127.0.0.6 *.azka.dev
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/hosts` only maps fixed IPv4/v6 addresses to fixed names, and vice versa. There are no wildcards available in its syntax.

If the rather simplistic `/etc/hosts` is inadequate for your requirements, you basically have two options:

- install and configure an alternative hostname resolution plug-in (see if your distribution has `libnss-*` or `nss-*` packages available) that provides names for local containers/VMs. For example, Debian has [`libnss-docker` for Docker containers](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/libnss-docker/nss-docker.8.en.html) and [`libnss-mymachines` for containers managed by `systemd-machined`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/libnss-mymachines/libnss_mymachines.so.2.8.en.html). If there is a pre-existing plugin in your distribution of choice that does what you want, this is probably the easiest way: just install a package and edit the `hosts:` line of the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file, and you're done.
- install a local DNS server (like `dnsmasq` or even BIND) and configure it to be authoritative for your private domain, and to forward any other requests to whatever you are using as your real DNS resolver servers. This is a bit more work and requires basic understanding of DNS server management - but then you will have literally all the features of the DNS available to you.